# What is the faster way to add the items from a class to an ArrayList to create a ListView?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
public class LengthConversion {
    public static final String M_TO_CM = "meter to centimeter";
    public static final String M_TO_MM = "meter to millimeter";
    public static final String M_TO_DM = "meter to decimeter";
    public static final String KM_TO_M = "kilometer to meter";
    public static final String INCH_TO_M = "inch to meter";
    public static final String FOOT_TO_M = "foot to meter";
    public static final String ASM_TO_M = "angstrom to meter";
    public static final String FM_TO_M = "fermi to meter";
    public static final String MILE_TO_KM = "mile to kilometer";}
```

I am adding these string to the ArrayList one by one by .add() function. Is there another way?

Comment: There are other ways but they are all *O(N).* Surely there are more important things to worry about?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need an enum:

```
public enum LengthConversion {
    M_TO_CM("meter to centimeter"),
    M_TO_MM("meter to millimeter"),
    M_TO_DM("meter to decimeter"),
    KM_TO_M("kilometer to meter"),
    INCH_TO_M("inch to meter"),
    FOOT_TO_M("foot to meter"),
    ASM_TO_M("angstrom to meter"),
    FM_TO_M("fermi to meter"),
    MILE_TO_KM("mile to kilometer");

    public final String conversion;

    LengthConversion(String conversion) {
        this.conversion = conversion;
    }
}
```

Comment: I read about enum, they said it is not recommended coz it will take time to handle it

Comment: @trylearning2022 Who are 'they', and why do they think enums 'take time to handle'? I don't know what this even means.

Comment: @OlehShatov How does this answer the question?

Comment: @user207421 i mean using enum can increase the file size as each value in an enum is treated as an object.

Comment: @trylearning2022 So space as opposed to time?

Comment: I think so, if numbers of enum we use are more

Comment: @trylearning2022 So ' they said it is not recommended coz it will take time to handle it' isn't true?

Comment: @user207421  yeah, with large project, enum is not recommended

Comment: @trylearning2022 But why not? The space cost is insignificant compared to the size of any large project, and they can save you a lot of code too if used well. It is meaningless to state things like 'increase the file size' without anything to compare it to.

Comment: @user207421 okey, thanks i got it.

Comment: @user207421 If you want a lot of optimization, you can look for Proguard. This mechanism convert enums to Integers after compile and provide other optimizations.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code